# What happens to XP Earned (below XP needed for next Skill Point) if a Commander is reassigned?

Tags: world-of-warships

The 50,228 HP [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IDxn.jpg):

1. What's its official term? 'XP Earned' is ambiguous; it can refer to XP earned by Commanders in, before I sent them to, Reserves.
2. What happens to it, if I reassign this Commander to Yugumo now?
3. To avoid losing it, should I wait until Commander attains 132,000 (the next Skill Point) before reassigning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the captain skills in warships, the 50k exp he currently has will not be removed or changed if you move him. The captains exp is separate to that of the boats exp. Much like the vehicles in other games like warthunder, you earn research points for the vehicles separately to your crew.

To answer your questions,

1. The term exp earned it refers to the exp that has been earned by that commander in battle, separate to the ships exp.
2. If you reassign the commander to the Yugumo he will not lose the exp he has earned or the skills points he will just continue to earn the exp on the new ship.
3. No you don't need to wait, don't forget each ship type benefits from a different commander skill set so moving a commander from ship to ship can be detrimental to the ships performance.